# How are generics managed by enums?

Tags: java, generics, enums

I've a parameterized interface:

```java
public interface MyInterface<T> {
    void run(T e);
}
```

And classes implementing the interface:

```java
public class MyClass1 implements MyInterface<SomeOtherClass1> {
    public void run(SomeOtherClass1 e) {
        // do some stuff with e
    }
}

public class MyClass2 implements MyInterface<SomeOtherClass2> {
    public void run(SomeOtherClass2 e) {
        // do some stuff with e
    }
}
```

The number of different MyClass*X* is known and exhaustive, and there is only one instance of each MyClass*X*, so I would like to use an enum:

```java
public enum MyEnum {
    MY_CLASS_1,
    MY_CLASS_2;
}
```

To be able to use `MyEnum.MY_CLASS_1.run(someOtherClass1);` for example (I would then have every instance of MyInterface in one same place). Is it even possible (and if yes, how)? Because I'm quite stuck for now...

---

What I tried yet:

```java
public enum MyEnum {

    MY_CLASS_1(new MyClass1()),
    MY_CLASS_2(new MyClass2());

    private MyInterface<?> instance;

    private MyEnum(MyInterface<?> instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    public void run(/* WhichType? */ e) {
        instance.run(e);
    }

}
```

In the above method, when using the type Object for the `e` parameter:

```java
public void run(Object e) {
    instance.run(e);
    //       ^^^
    // The method run(capture#3-of ?) in the type MyInterface<capture#3-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
}
```

The problem I think is with that `private MyInterface<?> instance` field: I need to know how is the instance parameterized, using something like `private MyInterface<T> instance`, but I can't find a working solution...

In short, I'm stuck ;)

---

PS: since the `run` methods bodies can be quite long, I'm trying to avoid anonymous classes within the enum:

```java
public enum MyEnum {

    MY_CLASS_1 {
        /* any method, etc. */
    },

    MY_CLASS_2 {
        /* any method, etc. */
    },

}
```

`MyEnum` would then become totally unreadable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible. That's one of the enum limitations I find most annoying, but all you can do is try to work around it (as you would have done in Java pre-5.0).

Only the enum itself can implement the interface and the generics must be specified at the enum level, so only `Object` or some common interface for those two would apply in your case.

Declaring any aspect that you want to treat polymorphically (the `run()` method, in your example) inside the enum itself (and overriding the behavior in each constant) is usually the best workaround. Of course, you need to loosen up your type safety requirements.

If you want to keep those strategies separated, you still need a `run(Object)` method inside the enum and that will be defined in each constant with some explicit cast, since you simply cannot have different method signatures per enum instance (or even if you can, they won't be visible as such from the outside).

---

A hint on how to trick the compiler, if you really want to do that rather than a redesign or explicit casts for each instance:

```
enum MyEnum implements MyInterface<Object> {
    MY_CLASS_1(new MyClass1()),
    MY_CLASS_2(new MyClass2());

    // you may also drop generics entirely: MyInterface delegate
    // and you won't need that cast in the constructor any more
    private final MyInterface<Object> delegate;

    MyEnum(MyInterface<?> delegate) {
        this.delegate = (MyInterface<Object>) delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(Object e) {
        delegate.run(e);
    }
}
```

The above will work and you'll get a `ClassCastException` (as expected) if you try to use `MyEnum.MY_CLASS_1.run()` with something other than `SomeOtherClass1`.

Comment: Good explanation but I don't like the solution for its lack of type safety.

Comment: @PaulBellora: I don't like it either :). And it's not even a solution, but merely a workaround. It only fits in if you can't live without the enum goodies (iterate through values, get values by name, ordinals, switch cases etc.)

Comment: @sp00m: I edited my code sample back to showing the parameterized version as the first option, in order to address your specific concern: "I need to know how is the instance *parameterized*"

Comment: Even if I don't like it that much neither, this is probably the only one <strike>solution</strike> workaround if I don't want to redesign the job... But I guess I would better redesign it without an enum ;) Thank you anyway, such a shame enums can't manage these kinds of generics!

Answer (score 2):

As [Costi points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20973306/697449), enums themselves [can't be generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207016/enum-constants-implementing-generic-interfaces-in-java). However I think I can identify where you went wrong in your design:

> There is only one instance of each MyClass*X*, so I would like to use
>   an enum:
>
> ```
> public enum MyEnum {
>     MY_CLASS_1,
>     MY_CLASS_2;
> }
> ```

You're saying that each of these classes is a singleton. So they should in fact *each be* an enum:

```
public enum MyClass1 implements MyInterface<SomeOtherClass1> {

    INSTANCE;

    @Override
    public void run(SomeOtherClass1 e) {
        // do some stuff with e
    }
}

public enum MyClass2 implements MyInterface<SomeOtherClass2> {

    INSTANCE;

    @Override
    public void run(SomeOtherClass2 e) {
        // do some stuff with e
    }
}
```

This makes more sense because if you think about it, you don't need to *enumerate* these two implementations, so there's no need for them to live together. It's enough to use [Josh Bloch's enum pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71399/697449) for each of them individually.

Comment: +1 This makes a lot of sense (and it's how `Functions` are implemented in Guava, for instance -- for the same reason). However, it gets a bit messy if you really need to refer to those instances collectively (as I mentioned in another comment).

Comment: Actually, I could use those singletons to replace MyClass1, MyClass2, etc., but the purpose of MyEnum were to have all the available instances of MyInterface in one same place, since there is a known exhaustive list in my case. I'll update my question to be more clear on this point, thanks anyway ;)